# How do I get the type of a dereferenced std::map iterator?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a map type:

```
typedef std::map<T1,T2> MapType;
```

I now want to get the type of a dereferenced iterator:

```
MapType mymap;
mymap[someT1variable] = someT2variable;
auto it = *mymap.begin();
```

How do I get the type of `it` from the type of `MapType`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `MapType::value_type`, which will be `std::pair<const T1, T2>`.

Read more at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: Just for the record: You can get the value type of an iterator without using the container via iterator_trais<Iterator>::value_type.